# Java socket stop reading from DataOutputStream

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream, overloading, connection

I have a problem with socket communication.
Sometimes reading from inputstream on client side stops working while the server is still sending new messages. I debugged the server so I know that is still working and sending messages to the outputstream. But on the client side read from inputstream is blocked. I can't debug this situation on client side. I only see difference in received messages on client side just before everything stops.

Example of good received message when everything works fine. Single send message in one line (I use DataInputStream.readUTF() method on client side and DataOutputStream.writeUTF(String msg) on server side. )

```
ADD;MB57,18-9,5,dd,10,10;
UP;MB15;20;14;20;13;1.0;
ADD;MB37,18-9,5,xx,10,10;
UP;MB13;20;14;20;13;1.0;
ADD;MB47,18-9,5,ww,10,10;
UP;MB13;20;14;20;13;1.0;
```

And this is happens just before my socket stop reading from input. One big mess. And everything that has been sent from the beginning in one line. It looks like the buffer overload O.o What happens?

```
   11-07 11:36:41.978: I/System.out(17980): 11;8;10;8;0.1;��UPPOS;MB8;16;8;16;7;1.0;��PATH;MB8��UPPOS;MB20;14;9;14;10;1.0;�� ADDMOB;MB20,14-10,6,mummy,50,50;�� PATH;MB20��UPPOS;MB50;12;8;12;7;1.0;��  PATH;MB50��UPPOS;MB13;15;11;14;11;1.0;��    PATH;MB19��PATH;MB8��UPPOS;MB20;14;10;13;10;1.0;��  PATH;MB20��UPPOS;MB50;12;7;12;6;1.0;��  PATH;MB50��UPPOS;MB13;14;11;14;10;1.0;��UPPOS;MB19;13;9;14;9;1.0;�� PATH;MB19��PATH;MB8��UPPOS;MB20;13;10;13;9;1.0;��ADDMOB;MB20,13-9,6,mummy,50,50;��  PATH;MB20��UPPOS;MB50;12;6;12;7;1.0;��  PATH;MB50��UPPOS;MB13;14;10;15;9;1.0;��!ADDMOB;MB13,15-9,5,chicken,10,10;�� PATH;MB13��UPPOS;MB19;14;9;14;10;1.0;��!ADDMOB;MB19,14-10,1,goblin,37,50;�� PATH;MB19��UPPOS;NP12;10;8;9;8;0.1;��UPPOS;MB8;16;7;17;7;1.0;��PATH;MB8��UPPOS;MB20;13;9;12;9;1.0;��    PATH;MB20��UPPOS;MB50;12;7;11;7;1.0;��  PATH;MB50��UPPOS;MB13;15;9;14;9;1.0;��  PATH;MB13��UPPOS;MB19;14;10;13;9;1.0;�� ADDMOB;MB19,13-9,1,goblin,37,50;��  PATH;MB19��UPPOS;MB8;17;7;16;7;1.0;��PATH;MB8��UPPOS;MB20;12;9;12;8;1.0;��UPPOS;MB50;11;7;12;7;1.0;��   PATH;MB50��UPPOS;MB13;14;9;14;10;1.0;��"ADDMOB;MB13,14-10,5,chicken,10,10;��    PATH;MB13�� PATH;MB19��UPPOS;MB8;16;7;16;8;1.0;��PATH;MB8�� PATH;MB20�� PATH;MB50��UPPOS;MB13;14;10;15;10;1.0;��    PATH;MB13��UPPOS;MB19;13;9;14;9;1.0;��  PATH;MB19��UPPOS;NP12;9;8;9;9;0.1;��UPPOS;MB8;16;8;16;7;1.0;��PATH;MB8��UPPOS;MB20;12;8;12;9;1.0;�� PATH;MB20��UPPOS;MB50;12;7;12;6;1.0;��  PATH;MB50��UPPOS;MB13;15;10;14;10;1.0;��UPPOS;MB19;14;9;13;9;1.0;�� PATH;MB19��PATH;MB8��UPPOS;MB20;12;9;12;8;1.0;��    PATH;MB50��UPPOS;MB13;14;10;14;9;1.0;��!ADDMOB;MB13,14-9,5,chicken,10,10;�� PATH;MB13�� PATH;MB19��UPPOS;MB8;16;7;16;6;1.0;��PATH;MB8��UPPOS;MB20;12;8;12;7;1.0;��  PATH;MB20�� PATH;MB50��UPPOS;MB13;14;9;14;10;1.0;��"ADDMOB;MB13,14-10,5,chicken,10,10;��    PATH;MB13��UPPOS;MB19;13;9;13;10;1.0;��!ADDMOB;MB19,13-10,1,goblin,37,50;�� PATH;MB19��UPPOS;NP12;9;9;9;8;0.1;��PATH;MB8��  PATH;MB20��UPPOS;MB50;12;6;11;6;1.0;��  PATH;MB50��UPPOS;MB13;14;10;14;9;1.0;��!ADDMOB;MB13,14-9,5,chicken,10,10;�� PATH;MB13��UPPOS;MB19;13;10;13;9;1.0;�� ADDMOB;MB19,13-9,1,goblin,37,50;��  PATH;MB19��UPPOS;MB8;16;6;16;7;1.0;��PATH;MB8�� PATH;MB20��UPPOS;MB50;11;6;12;6;1.0;��  PATH;MB50��UPPOS;MB13;14;9;15;9;1.0;��  PATH;MB13�� PATH;MB19��PATH;MB8��UPPOS;MB20;12;7;12;8;1.0;��    PATH;MB20�� PATH;MB50��UPPOS;MB13;15;9;14;9;1.0;��  PATH;MB13��UPPOS;MB19;13;9;13;10;1.0;��!ADDMOB;MB19,13-10,1,goblin,37,50;�� PATH;MB19��UPPOS;NP12;9;8;10;8;0.1;��UPPOS;MB8;16;7;16;8;1.0;��PATH;MB8��UPPOS;MB20;12;8;12;7;1.0;��    PATH;MB20�� PATH;MB50��UPPOS;MB13;14;9;15;9;1.0;��  PATH;MB13��UPPOS;MB19;13;10;13;11;1.0;��    PATH;MB19��UPPOS;MB8;16;8;16;9;1.0;��PATH;MB8��UPPOS;MB20;12;7;11;7;1.0;��  PATH;MB20��UPPOS;MB13;15;9;14;9;1.0;��  PATH;MB50�� PATH;MB13��UPPOS;MB19;13;11;13;10;1.0;��UPPOS;MB20;11;7;12;7;1.0;�� PATH;MB20��UPPOS;MB8;16;9;16;8;1.0;��   PATH;MB50��UPPOS;MB13;14;9;15;9;1.0;��  PATH;MB13��UPPOS;MB19;13;10;14;10;1.0;��UPPOS;NP12;10;8;11;8;0.1;�� PATH;MB20��UPPOS;MB8;16;8;16;7;1.0;��PATH;MB8�� PATH;MB50��UPPOS;MB13;15;9;14;9;1.0;��  PATH;MB13��UPPOS;MB19;14;10;15;9;1.0;�� ADDMOB;MB19,15-9,1,goblin,37,50;��  PATH;MB19��UPPOS;MB20;12;7;11;7;1.0;��  PATH;MB20��UPPOS;MB8;16;7;16;6;1.0;��PATH;MB8��UPPOS;MB50;12;6;12;7;1.0;��  PATH;MB50��UPPOS;MB13;14;9;13;9;1.0;��  PATH;MB13��UPPOS;MB19;15;9;14;9;1.0;��  PATH;MB19�� PATH;MB20��UPPOS;MB8;16;6;16;7;1.0;��PATH;MB8��UPPOS;MB50;12;7;12;8;1.0;��  PATH;MB50�� PATH;MB13��UPPOS;MB19;14;9;14;10;1.0;��!ADDMOB;MB19,14-10,1,goblin,37,50;�� PATH;MB19��UPPOS;MB20;11;7;12;7;1.0;��  PATH;MB20��UPPOS;MB8;16;7;16;8;1.0;��PATH;MB8��UPPOS;MB50;12;8;12;9;1.0;��  PATH;MB50��UPPOS;MB13;13;9;14;9;1.0;��  PATH;MB13��UPPOS;MB19;14;10;15;10;1.0;��    PATH;MB19��UPPOS;MB20;12;7;11;7;1.0;��  PATH;MB20��UPPOS;MB50;12;9;12;8;1.0;��  PATH;MB50��UPPOS;MB8;16;8;16;7;1.0;��PATH;MB8��UPPOS;MB13;14;9;13;9;1.0;��  PATH;MB13��UPPOS;MB19;15;10;15;9;1.0;�� ADDMOB;MB19,15-9,1,goblin,37,50;��UPPOS;NP12;11;8;10;8;0.1;��UPPOS;MB20;11;7;12;7;1.0;��UPPOS;MB8;16;7;16;6;1.0;��PATH;MB8��    PATH;MB13��UPPOS;MB50;12;8;11;8;1.0
```

Client side

```
private DataOutputStream out;
private Socket client;
private DataInputStream in;
private Thread inputListener;
public void createConnection(){
     try {
        client = new Socket(serverName, port);
         setOut(new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream()));
         in = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
         inputListener=new Thread(){
             public void run(){
                 try {
                     synchronized(in){
                         while(client!=null){
                             try{ 
                                 String read = new String(in.readUTF());
                                 /** do somethink with input msg */
                            } catch (java.io.UTFDataFormatException e1) {
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            } 
                         }
                     }
                 } catch (IOException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 } finally{
                     reconnect();
                 }
             }
         };
         inputListener.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void reconnect() {
    try {
        client.close();
        client=null;
        inputListener.interrupt();
        setOut(null);
        in.close();
        in=null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        System.out.println("RECONECT METHOD IN SOCKET");
    }
}
```

Server side

```
private DataOutputStream out;
private Socket client;
public Client(Socket client) {
    try {
        setOut(new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void sendMessage(String string) {
    try {
        getOut().writeUTF(string);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        disconected();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to show your code.

Comment: Even if i drop everythink from loop and leave only  String read=in.readUTF(); this sheet happens.

Answer (score 0):

You must be writing something else to the stream. Catching and ignoring `UTFDataFormatException` is no solution. Once you get it, you will never get back into sync with the sender.

NB Converting the result of `readUTF()` to a String is futile. It already is a String.

Comment: UTFDataFormatException never comes up because i send message in UTF8. This is default try catch block for method readUTF().  I also know that converting the string to a string does not make sense. But this is not a problem.

Comment: Writing redundant code is always a problem, and you've completely ignored my first sentence. The other possibility is that you're reading something else from the stream. It's hard to believe in an IDE that gives you a default `catch` block for `UTFDataFormatException` but not `EOFException`, if that is what you are obscurely alleging.

Comment: Redundant code is not a problem in this example and forget about it. 
You're right that default catch block for readUtf() is EOFException. But i don't received any errors from try catch block. I found solution for my problem in oracle documentation for socket implementations https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html I replaced DataInputStream for InputStreamReader
I'm not entirely sure but I think that the problem was buffer size for DataInputStream

Comment: No it wasn't, as `DataInputStream` doesn't have a buffer. Your 'solution' wouldn't have worked unless you also change the `DataOutputStream` to `BufferedWriter`, which you haven't stated.